# Play Console и выплаты Украина

Tags: android, google-play

Здравствуйте, хочу привязать карту приват банка к акаунту разработчика в Play Console. Подскажите пожалуйста, достаточно ли обычной приватовской карты для выплат или же нужно идти в отделение и открывать валютную карту?
В общем как правильно это все сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Карта должны быть валютной или мультивалютной. счет должен быть в USD. 
PS. Во многих банках при получении обычной карты, реквизиты на валюту уже открыт можно просто позвонить\написать и спросить как сделать.